# How to remove the last digit from the sequence?

Tags: java, regex

```
String sequence = "html1body2ul3li1p5a";
```

I'd like to remove the last digit(i.e., 5) from the sequence using replace method in Java. How can I capture the first digit seen from end of the sequence with regex? All non-digits are letters.

Comment: You sure you want to use regex for that? http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/10998/what-does-the-jamie-zawinskis-quotation-about-regular-expressions-mean

Comment: Do you want to capture or replace?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Replace

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
sequence = sequence.replaceAll("(.*)\\d", "$1");
```

Comment: You don't even need to match anything after `\\d`. `(.*)\\d` is sufficient. Note that there might be discrepancy with the description when the string contains new lines..

Answer (score 0):

```
sequence.replaceFirst("\\d([^\\d]*)$", "$1");
```

Comment: You are assuming there is only 1 character from the last digit to the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
String sequence = "html1body2ula3li1p5a";
System.out.println("Remove last char "+sequence.substring(1,sequence.length()-1));
System.out.println("Replace last char"+sequence.replaceAll("a$","XXX"));
```

Comment: That is if you already know where the digit is. This is not applicable for general case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too...

```
String sequence = "html1body2ul3li1p5a";
sequence = sequence.replaceAll("(\\d+)(?!.*\\d)", "");
```

Comment: You are capturing more than "last digit". You are currently capturing the last contiguous sequence of digits.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to replace the last 0-9 character you can use:

```
myString.replaceAll("\\d+(?=\D*$)", "")
```

This will replace the last digit in the applied string with nothing.

```
myString.replaceAll("\\d+(?=\D*$)", "")
```

This will replace the last group of digits in the applied string with nothing (e.g. the `93` in `sdfsdflih193a`).